# Home assignment involving Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I was discussing with a friend the following question and its solution by our teacher:

> In a dish there are 2 types of cell cultures: $W,V$. $V$ constitutes 20% of the dish. The life expectancy of $V$ is exponentially distrubuted with expectancy of 8 days, and $W$'s is exponentially distrubuted with expectancy of 5 days. Their life expectancies are independent of each other.

> Given that the dish's life expectancy was longer than 7.1 days, what is the probability that $V$ is the one which has lived this long?

The solution defined $A$ as the event that V has lived more than 7.1 days and $\bar A$ as the event that W has lived, and so
$$
P(A | Dish > 7.1) = \frac{P(Dish > 7.1 | A)P(A)}{P(Dish>7.1)}=\frac{P(Dish > 7.1 | A)P(A)}{P(Dish > 7.1 | A)P(A) + P(Dish > 7.1 | \bar A)P(\bar A)} = \frac{0.2(1-F_V(7.1))}{0.2(1-F_V(7.1)) + 0.8(1-F_W(7.1))}=\frac{0.2\cdot 0.412}{0.2\cdot 0.412 + 0.8\cdot 0.242}=0.299
$$

But it doesn't seem right to me. $V$ and $W$ could both have lived longer than 7.1 days, so $A$ and $\bar A$ aren't complementary to each other.

Our way of solving this was as follows
$$
P(V >7.1 | W,V > 7.1) = \frac{P(W,V > 7.1 \cap V> 7.1)}{P(W,V > 7.1)}=\frac{P(V > 7.1)}{P(W > 7.1)+ P(V > 7.1) -P(W>7.1)P(V>7.1)} = \frac{1-F_V(7.1)}{1-F_V(7.1) + 1-F_W(7.1)- (1-F_V(7.1))(1-F_w(7.1))}=\frac{0.412}{0.412 + 0.242 - 0.242\cdot 0.412}=0.743
$$

Is our solution correct or the teacher's and why?

Comment: Not sure the scenario is clear.  As you say, the "official" solution appears to imagine that it is impossible for *both* $V$ and $W$ to have survived, but that rule isn't stated anywhere.  Is the survival of one someone dependent on the survival of the other?  I'd have assumed independence.

Comment: And the $20\%$ seems irrelevant.  As I say, I think the scenario is unclear.

Comment: Note:  My solution differs from both of the solutions you present, though I think you just garbled the arithmetic at the end.  $\frac {.412}{.412+.242-.242\times .412}=.743$ which matches my answer.

Comment: I think it comes down to asking what is meant by "the dish's life expectancy".    That's just a hard phrase to parse.  Your teacher appears to be contemplating the following scenario:  after $7.1$ days you pick a spot on the dish (uniformly at random) and confirm that this spot is still live, what then is the probability that you picked a $V$ spot?  In that case, you know it is either $V$ or $W$ and not both. And in that case the $20\%$ is indeed relevant.  I agree it is hard to guess that this scenario is what the problem intended.

Comment: The wording of the question is unclear

Comment: @lulu 1. No, it was unequivocally stated in the original question that their life expectancy are independent of each other, So that's what bothered me too.
2. I agree, I didn't use that either.
3. Yes you're correct, I checked again and my last calculation wasn't corrent. Edited it now.
4. Though I translated the question, it is as close to the original as it can get. After reading what you've said, I tend to agree that the solution doesn't particularly fit the question quite well. Maybe they've changed the question a bit at some point but left the solution.

Comment: To the best of my understanding, by "the dish's life expectancy" they mean the life expectancy of the cell culture which survived the longer than the two.

Comment: As I say, it seems clear that the teacher was following the scenario I described. The "dish's life expectancy" simply doesn't make sense.  The problem isn't about the life expectancy of the (group) culture.  It's just about whether or not something is alive at a particular point in time.  But, I wouldn't worry about it too much.  Badly phrased problems are sadly common.  Just ask the teacher how they interpreted the problem.